# When defining directory path, should a trailing slash be included?

Tags: programming-practices, naming, include

Say I'm defining a directory and then including files from it. Is it better practice to do:

```
define('PATH', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/');
require PATH.'header.php;
```

or:

```
define('PATH', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/includes');
require PATH.'/header.php;
```

Comment: Note that you may replace "/" by `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, a constant which will be replaced by "\" on Windows. It helps to be consistent.

Answer (score 11):

To avoid ambiguity, you should always add the trailing slash.

Not all files have extensions, so if you use this consistently in your codebase, you (and others) will be able to tell whether a path references a directory or a file at a glance.

Comment: Additionally, since extra slashes are ignored you won't accidentally attempt to open nonexistent files

Comment: This is always what I thought too until I realized that `Directory.GetParent("C:\stuff\")` will actually return `C:\stuff` instead of `C:\` as you would expect